# Why am i unable to enter code in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[This opens whenever I start writing code in a kernel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4bQT.png).stack.imgur.com/GQPYA.png

Expected: print("hellooo")

i am unable to type in the kernel, there's no error message, since there's no code.

I tried doing this multiple times, by closing and starting it again, but same thing happens over and over again.

Comment: Try to improve your question, there are many formatting problems (lack of brackets, typos, wrong link insertion (template: `[<title>](<link>))).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry you have just opened command palette, search for **confirm restart kernel** **and click it** , or simply press the esc you should be ready to go.